# Is there an equivalent to Xcode's quick jump bar (to navigate Swift MARK annotations within a file)?

Tags: neovim, macvim, navigation

[image: vim screenshot of swift pragma marks]

Does a rough equivalent to this Xcode quick jump bar feature exist as a Vim plugin? I haven't been able to find any good leads on one in my research.

It's a way to navigate sections in a file - in the case of Swift, the `// MARK: sections annotated like this`.

Answer (score 1):

You could search `/MARK` and then hit `n`, but faster and easier in my opinion is

```
global/MARK/list
```

And then you type `:` and the line number when you get the list of results.

The command can be shortened to `:g/MARK/#`, if you like, or mapped to a keysequence to make it even faster:

```
nnoremap <leader>m :global/MARK/#<CR>:
```

Comment: Thanks, `/list` is news to me!

Comment: @aehlke the command is actually `:list` if you want to read the help :) you’re welcome.